# using RDCOMClient to pull emails from a folder

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I have a script to pull emails from a certain folder, however the number of emails being returned in R does not match how many emails are in the folder. I think Outlook or R is truncating the folder at a certain max size of items.

Is there any way around this?

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

fld <- outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6)
fld = fld$folders(fldr)
Cnt = fld$Items()$Count()
emails <- fld$items
emails()$Count()

## 319 vs 321
```

If I open that folder in Outlook I can see it's truncated:
[image]

Is there anyway to increase this view in Outlook?

Comment: There are some other tools that can read mapi including mapitool (ruby program) and Apache tika (see rtika package on github).

Comment: I noticed that rtika appeared on CRAN in the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open the folder in the online mode (Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi, or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) in any language, including R) or you can either (a) turn cached mode off in the Exchange Account properties or make it sync all items instead of time-limited range.